# PyFilesystem can't find existing file in tar-fs

Tags: python-3.x, tar

I wrote a little script to download and extract VSCode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import shutil
from io import BytesIO
from fs.tarfs import TarFS
from fs.copy import copy_fs

target_install_path = "~/Downloads/VSCode"
dl_link = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620884"

print("Sending Requests")
r = requests.get(dl_link, stream=True)
if not r.status_code == 200:
    print("Error, status code: ", r.status_code)
    exit()

tar_data = BytesIO()
print("Downloading Data")
shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, tar_data)
tar_data.seek(0)
tar_fs = TarFS(tar_data)
print("Extracting")
copy_fs(tar_fs, target_install_path)
```

The problem is, that during execution the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/tarfs.py", line 259, in getinfo
    member = self._tar.getmember(self._encode(_path))
  File "/~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 1749, in getmember
    raise KeyError("filename %r not found" % name)
KeyError: "filename 'VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/node_modules/diagnostic-channel' not found"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_vscode", line 23, in <module>
    copy_fs(tar_fs, target_install_path)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/copy.py", line 31, in copy_fs
    walker=walker, on_copy=on_copy)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/copy.py", line 225, in copy_dir
    for dir_path, dirs, files in walker.walk(src_fs, _src_path):
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/walk.py", line 269, in walk
    for dir_path, info in _walk:
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/walk.py", line 340, in _walk_breadth
    for info in self._scan(fs, dir_path, namespaces=namespaces):
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fs/walk.py", line 236, in _scan
    six.reraise(type(error), error)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
fs.errors.ResourceNotFound: resource '/VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/node_modules/diagnostic-channel' not found
```

If I copy the r.raw to a file object on my disk, and then use tar to extract it, the files that fs_copy can't find are in there.

Does someone have an idea, what the problem might be? 
I use python 3.6 and fs 2.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the PyFilesystem library, for details see: https://github.com/PyFilesystem/pyfilesystem2/issues/160